# How does the TextView compute mScrollX after setting gravity to "center_horizontal"

Tags: android, view, scroll, textview

After setting TextView's gravity to 'center_horizontal', the value of mScrollX becomes a very large number. Anybody know how this large number being computed?

Comment: The number you are seeing is just a reference. What is the point of your question?

Comment: @Chisko,It's about EditView's fading edge behavior. The android default behavior is fading strength will be 0 when scrolling to the beginning/end of text(horizontally). But after I set gravity to 'center_horizontal', this default behavior doesn't work. I checked the implementation in View class#getLeftFadingEdgeStrength, only when mScrollX == 0, the fading effect will be dismissed (getLeftFadingEdgeStrength returns 0.0f). But when gravity is centered, the mScrollX becomes a very large number.

Comment: To me that makes perfect sense, why would you want a centered item to fade edges? Maybe if you restate your question with the problem you are facing can result in an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Chisko, I don't think it's a reference. It's the same value as what returns from computeHorizontalScrollOffset(), and it increases when text longer than textview, which means scrolling to left.

Comment: I'm sure there is a simpler answer to your problem without having to deal with the core system and how it calculates stuff.

Comment: @Chisko, since fading edge means there are more content beyond view window, I don't think it should relates to gravity. Sure, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You probably will want to wrap whatever views you want to fade in another container and set the gravity on it